# Remove the line with unwanted characters from text file using java

Tags: java

I want to filter out the line in a text file which is having many words that were not recognize properly. The word will recognize with special symbols such as **@/(&#%-**"

For example the file given with lines:

```
I like to eat.
I &^#@dj dsaasd.
I like to drink.
```

And the output should be like:

```
I like to eat.
I like to drink.
```

It will remove the line with the special symbols.

Comment: Ok, you've specified your task. What is your question? Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: (0) Create temporary text file, (1) Read original file nine-by-line, (2) check if currently read line `contains` one of characters which you don't want (3) if it doesn't contain any special characters write that line to temporary file. (4) After all lines ware handled remove remove original file, and rename temporary file to to replace original one.

Answer (score 1):

Read file content as lines, you are using java :

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path, encoding);
```

Now you need to apply your filter

lines.filter(line -> line.matches(regex that you want));

```
Then use the collector that you want

To apply this solution you need to learn Streams and lambda expression and you use java8 and higher.
```